# Pass just one field via AJAX with Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, ajax

I have a VERY simple HTML form with just one `<input type='text'>` field, an email address, that I need to pass back to a Python script via AJAX. I can't seem to receive the value on the other end. (And can all the JSON encoding/decoding be avoided, since there's just one field?)

Here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.htm')

@app.route('/start', methods=['POST'])
def start():
    # next line outputs "email=myemail@gmail.com"
    app.logger.debug(request.json);
    email = request.json['email'];
    # next line ALSO outputs "email=myemail@gmail.com"
    app.logger.debug(email);
    return json.dumps({ 'status': 'OK', 'email': email })

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

And the Javascript that sends the AJAX from the HTML side--

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    d = "email=" + $('#email').val();  // this works correctly

    // next line outputs 'sending data: myemail@gmail.com'
    console.log("sending data: "+d);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ url_for('start') }}",
        data: JSON.stringify(d),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ");

            // next line outputs 'Object {email: "email=myemail@gmail.com", status: "OK"}'
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify is used to turn an object into a JSON-formatted string, but you don't have an object, just a string. Try this:

```
var d = { email: $('#email').val() };
```

`JSON.stringify(d)` will now turn that into a JSON-formatted string:

`{email: "myemail@gmail.com"}` which can be parsed by flask.

---

To do this without JSON:

```
var d = { email: $('#email').val() };
...
// AJAX
    data: d,
    success: ...
```

This will turn `{email: "myemail@gmail.com"}` into `email=mymail@gmail.com` and send that as body of the POST request. In Flask, use `request.form['email']`.